# Rewrite all web requests in Chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, url, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite all web requests in Chrome, including js/css includes and ajax requests. For example:

```
change http://foo.com/index.htm
to http://bar.com?url=http://foo.com/index.htm
```

I've tried to use xrewrite extension for chrome but it seems to run recursively so I end up with a url similar to the one below but with more recursions:

```
http://bar.com?url=http://bar.com?url=http://bar.com?url=http://foo.com/index.htm
```

Comment: Is there an *exceptions* list? If not, have your tried tweaking your regexp?